# chrome computed style overwritting my styles

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

chrome set my body height to 113px when the height is not set in my css.  please help.

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px; 
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Many things that you don't explicitly set will be automatically calculated by the browser, including the body height (which defaults to the combined height of all contained content with position: static). However, without seeing all of your CSS and knowing your environment, we can't determine if this is being overridden by another style.